# Запрос на Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

есть таблица пользователей

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

таблица данных пользователя

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

таблица заказанных услуг

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

таблица избранных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

таблица диалогов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

таблица сообщений

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как мне вывести всех пользователей, пол которых gender != Auth::user()->id сортируя их по user_services.top desc

- нужно проверить в избранных ли этот пользователя у Auth::user()->id, есть ли с ним диалог dialogs и есть ли приветственное сообщение от Auth::user()->id users.id

пока что у меня так

```
 $users = DB::table('users')
            ->leftJoin('user_attributes','user_attributes.user_id','users.id')
            ->leftJoin('cities','cities.id','user_attributes.city_id')
            ->leftJoin('user_services','user_services.user_id','users.id')
            ->join('favorites', function($join)
            {
                $join->on('favorites.favorite_id','=', 'users.id')
                    ->where('favorites.user_id','=', Auth::user()->id);
            })
            ->join('dialogs', function($join)
            {
                $join->on('dialogs.recipient_id','=', 'users.id')
                    ->where('dialogs.user_id','=', Auth::user()->id)
                    ->orWhere('dialogs.recipient_id','=',  Auth::user()->id)
                    ->where('dialogs.user_id','=', 'users.id');
            })
            ->join('dialog_messages', function($join)
            {
                $join->on('dialog_messages.dialog_id','=', 'dialogs.id')
                    ->where('dialog_messages.user_id','=', 'users.id')
                    ->where('dialog_messages.status','=', 3);
            })
            ->where('user_attributes.gender','!=', Auth::user()->attributes->id)
            ->orderBy('user_services.top','desc')
            ->orderBy('users.id','desc')
            ->paginate(50);
```

но проблема, как мне вывести флаги 1 - есть в избранных, 0 нет в избранных, 1 есть приветсnвенное сообщение со status - 3, 0 нет сообщения со status - 3

до этого было так, но это ужас, и хочется как-то впихнуть в один запрос

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                    ->leftJoin('user_attributes','user_attributes.user_id','users.id')
                    ->leftJoin('user_services','user_services.user_id','users.id')
                    ->where('user_attributes.gender','!=', Auth::user()->attributes->id)
                    ->orderBy('user_services.top','desc')
                    ->orderBy('users.id','desc')
                    ->paginate(50);

        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $dialog = Dialog::where('user_id','=', Auth::user()->id)
                ->where('recipient_id','=', $user->id)
                ->orWhere('recipient_id','=', Auth::user()->id)->where('user_id','=', $user->id)->first();
            if ($dialog){
                $user->dialog = $dialog->id;
                $like = $dialog->messages->where('user_id','=', Auth::user()->id)
                    ->where('status','=', 3)->first();

                if ($like) $user->like = 1;else $user->like = 0;
            }else{
                $user->dialog = 0;
                $user->like = 0;
            }
            $city = City::where('id','=',$user->attributes->city_id)->first();
            $user->city = $city['title'];

            $count = UserPrivate::where('user_id','=', $user->id)->where('published','=',1)->count();
            $user->images = $count;
            $favorite = Favorite::where('user_id','=', Auth::user()->id)->where('favorite_id','=', $user->id)->first();
            if ($favorite) $user->favorite = 1;else $user->favorite = 0;
        }
```